# Vaadin @JavaScript for different builds

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I use Vaadin @JavaScript annotation to load JavaScript files for my application. It works great but I would need different JavaScript loaded for differents builds.
The idea is to have something like these:

```
@JavaScript("url.from.properties.or.pom")
```

So for DEV I would get @JavaScript("https://example.com/test/js/embed.js") and for PROD @JavaScript("https://example.com/production/js/embed.js"). The script url value should be taken from application.properties or pom.xml.

I cannot figure out how to do it. I use Vaadin 8 with Maven and Spring Boot. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct support for what you want to do, but I can come up with three different solutions that you could consider.

1. Register a `DependencyFilter` that dynamically rewrites the dependency URL from the annotation depending on the situation.
2. Create separate Java classes for each case (with all the actual functionality in a shared super class). You can then have either runtime logic or use e.g. different Spring configurations to choose exactly which class to use.
3. Remove the `@JavaScript` annotation and instead call `JavaScript.eval` from `onAttach` to somehow dynamically inject the script you want.